# Necessary and sufficient condition so that L be equal to L*

Tags: formal-languages

Given L a formal language, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions so that L = L*

 Definition of L* is:
$$
L^*=\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}_0}L^i=L^0\cup L^1\cup L^2\dots
$$

Comment: It just means that $L$ is a submonoid of the free monoid.

Answer (score -1):

A condition, what is neccessary and sufficient is $\{\lambda\} \cup L^2 \subseteq L$, where $\lambda$ denotes the empty word.

For the proof, note that on one side, $\{\lambda\} \cup L^2 = L^0\cup L^2 \subseteq L^*$ by definition. On the other side, we will prove by induction that $L^i \subseteq L$. For $i = 0$, $L^0 = \{\lambda\} \subseteq L$ by our condition. Now suppose, for some $i$, we have $L^i \subseteq L$. We now have 
$$ L^{i+1} = LL^i \subseteq L L = L^2 \subseteq L,$$
the last inclusion by our condition.

Comment: Why the downvote?